# Find redundant braces in an input string

Tags: python, interview-questions, stack, balanced-delimiters

I am solving interview questions from [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/redundant-braces/).

> Problem : Write a program to validate if the input string has redundant braces
>
> Return `0/1` :
>
> `0 --> NO`
>
> `1 --> YES`
>
> Input will be always a valid expression and operators allowed are only + , * , - , /
>
> Example:
>
> `((a + b)) has redundant braces so answer will be 1`
>
> ```
> (a + (a + b)) doesn't have have any redundant braces so answer will be 0
> ```

How can I improve my solution?

```
def redundant_braces(exp):
    """returns 1 if any redundant bracket is present else returns 0"""   
    cnt = 0  ## counter for elements popped from stack
    if '(' not in exp:
        return 0
    stack = []
    ## add elements in stack until closing bracket encountered
    for i in exp:
        stack.append(i)
        if i == ')' :
            stack.pop()  ## remove the last closing bracket
            while stack.pop() != '(':  ## check for last opening bracket
                cnt += 1
            if cnt  == 0 or cnt == 1:
                return 1

        cnt = 0  ## reset counter to zero
    return 0


assert redundant_braces("(a)") == 1
assert redundant_braces("(a+(a+b))") == 0   
assert redundant_braces("(a+b)")   == 0
assert redundant_braces("(a*b)+(b*c)") == 0
assert redundant_braces("(a+((a+b)))") == 1
assert redundant_braces("((a+(a+b)))") == 1
```

Comment: `assert redundant_braces("(a*b)+(b*c)") == 0` that's not right; according to common math rules the answer should be 2 redundant braces (output = 1 for YES), as `*` takes precedence over `+`. This is a tree building question.

Comment: Also `(a + (a + b))` is definitely redundant